Access denied when navigate to folders
I upload my html code to S3 and enable the static website option. It works fine only for /index.html
If I navigate to an html file like products/index.html it works fine, but when I navigate to the folder like products/ it fails with AccessDenied.
What is the problem? It should recognise the index.html from inside the folder
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "__POLICYID__",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "__SSID__",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::__MYDOMAIN__/*"
        }
    ]
}


Check your static website hosting settings and ensure you've configured your index document to be index.html

Is the entire bucket publicly-readable or at least the pages you want to view (done via S3 bucket policy)?

@jarmod I update the question with policy details. I think with this policy entire bucked is readable. Index.html is set in website hosting, and it works but only for /index not for other folders like products/

Finally this the solution is a lambda@edge thath replace any path finished with / for path/index.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/

The issue lies in how S3 static website hosting handles folder paths and index.html files within subdirectories.
in order to make S3 recognize index.html for folder paths, you need to configure the Default Root Object or ensure that the website hosting settings handle index.html for subdirectories. you can find that Under Static Website Hosting with the Properties Tab, ensure the Index Document is set to index.html. This setting tells S3 to serve index.html when a folder path is accessed.
like that when you navigate to https://<bucket-name>.s3-website-<region>.amazonaws.com/products/ it should work fine.

Now I see that the problem is not in s3. It is in cloudfront, Cloudfront is the responsible for this behavior.

yes, same type of configuration need to be made on cloudfront, If the Default Root Object setting in your CloudFront distribution is not configured to index.html, navigating to a directory like products/ will not automatically serve products/index.html.

I have index.html in Default Root Objects, but only works for /index.html not for subdirectories

Yes right, CloudFront's Default Root Object applies only to the root path / (e.g., /index.html) but does not automatically append index.html for /something/.. . To work through that you can create Lamda@edge to rewrite the requests to /index.html for the subdirectories . Or you need to use the website directly from S3 without the cloudfront .

I think you can also configure the cloudfront to redirect the 403 to index.html, it may solve this issue as well and make the index.html as the default

No, because this forces you to put / in front. Any 403 redirects to /index not /directory/index.html I think Lambda edge is the solution

Yeah, if you want a solution which will keep your url appearing with /directory , then Lambds edge with your current setup.
